# How to make mat-chips checked unchecked?

Tags: html, css, angular-material

I am make `mat-chips` checked unchecked , but for specific area (only labels click) only click to checked unchecked work, now i want to click any where on mat-chips it is checked unchecked, below html code i am using.

```
<mat-chip-list formControlName="sample">  
     <mat-chip  mat-raised-button>
         <div mat-card-avatar class=""></div>  
                  <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" 
                        [checked]="checked" value="sample" 
                        id="sample" name="sample"> 
                  <label for="sample">sample</label>
        </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

[see my mat-chip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2vOZ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right, then you want to be able to click anywhere on the mat-chip to change the state of your checkbox.

As you're already binding the `checked` property of your input to a field called `checked` in your component, all you have to do is to register a click event handler on your mat-chip that modifies the field `checked`. In addition to that I changed the oneway checked binding to a two way binding. As there was an issue with multiple click events, I added `(click)='$event.stopPropagation()'` to the checkbox.

Something like this should work:

```
<mat-chip-list formControlName="sample"> 
 <mat-chip  mat-raised-button (click)="checked=!checked">
     <div mat-card-avatar class=""></div>  
              <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" 
                      [(ngModel)]='checked'
                    id="sample" name="sample" (click)='$event.stopPropagation()'>
              <label for="sample">sample</label>
    </mat-chip>
```

[Link to Stackblitz live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-sytgx7)

Comment: Not Working ,Sir.